# Cannot reach web method with Flexigrid call from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery-plugins, webmethod

I implemented the followig web method (file Notes.asmx):

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public object getNotesData ()
    {

        Guid contactId = new Guid("dc53b9a3-bde1-4810-88dd-3db2581f29b8");

        var data = BusinessObjectFactory.GetContactNotes(contactId);
        string serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

        return serialized;
    }
```

The method simply return some data referred to a contact.
I tested the method separately and it returns the records properly.

In an aspx page I use the following Flexigrid syntax to call this web method for retrieve the data:

```
$(function ()
        {
            $("#flex1").flexigrid(
            {
            url: 'WebService/Notes.asmx/getNotesData',
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel : [
            { display: 'NOTEID', name: 'NOTEID', width: 40, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            { display: 'Title', name: 'Title', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
            ],
            sortname: "Title",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            title: "Notes_TITLE",
            useRp: true,
            rp: 10,
            showTableToggleBtn: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 370,
            singleSelect: true
            }
            );
       });
```

However debugging the code I see that the server is never reached from the flexigrid call. In the browser the aspx page has a "Connection Error" in the Flexigrid UI.

I use other web methods invoked with Ajax/Json and jQuery and they work fine. It is not a matter of wrong path since the aspx file is saved on the same server and in the directory above the one containing the web service (folder called WebService).

**Any suggestions why I cannot reach the server using Flexigrid sintax?**

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the path to your web service is WebService/Notes.asmx/getNotesData?
have a look with firebug, it's probably the wrong url

Comment: The path is right since I tested from the code behind (keeping  same path) and it works, therefore I woulkd exclude a wrong URL issue.

I work in an intranet where IE is the only browser used (and usable) therefore I cannot use Firebug directly. I will try with Fiddler or a similar program to get where the connection problem lies.